# Wildfly Elytron: Principal not available in SimpleSecurityManager

Tags: wildfly, elytron

I implemented an authentication mechanism similar to CustomHeaderHttpAuthenticationMechanism in https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/tree/master/simple-http-mechanism, using PasswordGuessEvidence and also the other Callbacks mentioned in the example. Reason for the custom mechanism is that beside a simple credential check we need also to validate more constraints to check if a user is validated.

Stepping through this authentication mechanism looks quite good, the authenticationComplete method is called and also the authorizeCallback is successful. However, when accessing an EJB via a resteasy endpoint (EJB is annotated with @SecurityDomain and @RolesAllowed...) the SimpleSecurityManager.authorize method fails because the securityContext.getUtil method neither provides a principal nor something else. If accessing a method annotated by @PermitAll it is successful.

I guess the principal should be created by the ServerAuthenticationContext when working through the different callbacks, right?

How do I manage that the SimpleSecurityManager can recognize the principal, would I need to create it in my authentication mechanism, and how?

Answer (score 0):

In this case it sounds like your EJB deployment has not been mapped to the WildFly Elytron security domain so is still making use of PicketBox security in the EJB tier which is why you are not seeing the identity already established.

Within the EJB subsystem you can also add an application-security-domain mapping to map from the security domain specified in the deployment to the WildFly Elytron security domain.

FYI at some point in the future when we are ready to remove PicketBox from the server these additional mappings will no longer be required, they are just unfortunately needed at the moment whilst we have both solutions in parallel.